# How to use the snefru256 hash function?

Tags: python, hash

I need to get data via an API, that requires that I add a checksum that needs to be hashed via the snefru256 hash function.

The documentation for the API shows a calculation for the checksum written in PHP:

```
$str = $time.".".$sensor.".".$token;
$checksum = hash("snefru256",$str);
```

I have tested the snefnu hash function with https://md5calc.com/hash/snefru, and the resulting encoded string works for the API I am using.

I have been unable to find a way to use the snefru256 hash function in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to put this into your programm :

```
import requests
def snefru256(text):
    data = ""
    for x in text:
        if x != " ": data += x
        else: data += "+"
    req = requests.get('https://md5calc.com/hash/snefru256.json/' + data)
    return req.json()
```

After defined, you can call the function using this :

```
hash = snefru("your text here.")
```

If it does not work try adding a "b" before the string. E.g. :

```
hash = snefru(b"your text here")
```

If it does not work, I dont know what I can tell you to do.

Comment: Oh my... The code had some errors. I just corrected them.